# Decimal conversion using specific format

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, string-formatting

I am using the format below in my datagrid. My local machine gives me the result I want:

```
105,000.42
```

But on the server, it gives me:

```
1,05,000.42
```

Please help me fix this error.

This is my partial code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblibilling" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#Bind( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"pbilling","{0:0,0.00}") %>' >
</asp:Label>
```

I am not able to fix this error. Please help me fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblibilling" runat="server" 
    Text='<%#Bind( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"pbilling","{0:#,0,,.00}") %>' >
</asp:Label>
```

I copied it from a project I did

Comment: I'm sorry for that I didn't read your questions very well. I though you wanted to display millionth.